# setVisibility to View using Integer

Tags: java, android, visibility

I'm trying to set visibility in Android to many views at once and I want to send Integer to this views instead copying and pasting my code.

```
        if (gameIsActive == false) {

        startButton.setVisibility(startButton.VISIBLE);
        greetingTextView.setVisibility(greetingTextView.VISIBLE);

        gridLayout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        timerTextView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        scoreTextView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        checkerTextView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    } else {

        startButton.setVisibility(startButton.INVISIBLE);
        greetingTextView.setVisibility(greetingTextView.INVISIBLE);

        gridLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        timerTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        scoreTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        checkerTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

}
```

I know that `INVISIBLE = 4` and `VISIBLE = 0`, but creating `int` doesn't help.

```
int isVisible = 0;
startButton.setVisibility(startButton.isVisible);
```

How can I switch visible to invisible?

Comment: View.VISIBLE, View.INVISIBLE are already integers. You can use them directly.

Comment: Also always use View.GONE , since when a object is invisibile it still using the space in the layout while View.GONE really disappear that object from the view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had something like that:

```
void setViewsVisibility(int visibility){
    view.setVisibility(visibility);
    //oher views
}
```

And use it like that:

```
setViewsVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Hope it will help!

Comment: I wanted to optimize code and not copy all these views, but now I see that it doesn't work like that. So, I'll just leave this code how it is.
Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Idk, how to optimize it more, because actually you have to set visibility for your views anyway. You can try to use DataBinding. With it you can attach your views visibility to some boolean  variable and they will change it when boolean changed, it will look better, but I dont think that you must use DataBinding only for this purpose. But anyway you may look at this [link](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/) and think about it.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this

```
public void changeVisibility(int visibility)
{
    startButton.setVisibility(visibility);
    // you can add here as many as views you want
}
```

and

```
changeVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

> startButton.setVisibility(isVisible);

Answer (score 0):

You can also do something like this

```
Button.setVisibility(isVisible == 0 ? View.Visible : View.Invisible);
```

Where View.Visible = 0, View.Invisible = 4 & View.Gone = 8.

you can just pass the integer value too.
if you are getting some kind of error share the log then.